# An easy way to embed custom information when in the field

Tags: metadata, filenames

My company needs to take a large number of product photo's in the field.

The make sense of the file when they come to download them, they would like to store custom products id number either as meta data or as part of the filename.

If they was a studio situation, I would imagine you would download the images directly to PC and have a second person embedding data as the pictures where being taken but this is for an outdoors situation.

How would go about this?

One random idea I had was to use a camera that ran android and a bluetooth keyboard (for speed)

I there a better way, ideally we would prefer to use a "pro" camera?

Comment: Have you considered using a small white board, just in shot with details written on it? i dont know if you will ALWAYS frame up as the final shot as it is intended to be used, but if not, and you have to crop, this is how i'd do it...

Comment: Is a laptop not viable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a DLSR I can think of a few ways, all of them would involve some kind of scripting or post-process though.  Essentially you need to know what product was in front of the camera and when.  Depending on how often you'll need to do it will determine what level of automation you can/should bring to bear.

The most low-tech solution would be to take a leaf out of the videographers book and shoot a whiteboard or chalkboard with the details of each product before you shoot it.  Then when you go through in post using bridge or similar the title frames will be obvious for manual renaming or tagging.

Alternatively you could log when each product is shot using a tablet/laptop like matching up a GPS log.  As long as you sync the times up it would be relatively simple for someone with the appropriate skills to write an app/script to do that for you.

Or there is the eye-fi option mentioned by AJ.  Again, that can be automated fairly easily to automatically add a tag/rename files as they appear.

Comment: If you're ok with programming / have someone who is you can even automate it. Take a clear enough shot of the info-table before each actual product (maybe with a QR code even), and then on the computer pull that info with OCR and paste it onto the files. Or do it manually, depends on how many pics there are

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind for me would be to use a DSLR that either includes Wifi capability or one that supports a Wireless File Transmitter.  You could also use a cheaper solution such as an Eve-Fi card.  These could send photos to either a laptop, a tablet or a smartphone wirelessly and the photos could be tagged with whatever information is needed there.  It also would let one person shoot and one person tag, just like you would in a studio setup.

Answer (score -1):

The solution you are looking for is Wi-Pics.
Wi-Pics offers a variety of solutions for different workflows, all of which allow you to not only embed custom data (such as barcodes and custom data fields) into the EXIF header of the JPG, but can also rename the images with any or all of that data, before transmitting them to your FTP server or printing station, as you shoot!
For more info, visit our website at www.wipicsmobile.com or via email at WiPics.SC100@UnitedImagingSolutions.com